# Android react native app displays white screen unless Chrome debug

Tags: react-native

My Android app on my Android emulator displays a white screen whenever it boots up, unless I press debug in Chrome, then my app runs fine. Is this normal behaviour? I'm running on a Mac.

Comment: Same problem here! After updating RN from 0.15 to 0.17 i get this problem....